# Strings manipulation

Tags: ruby, string

Sure enough there are more than a way to convert the following strings either form left to right or vice versa

```
"content-management-systems" <=> "Content Management Systems"
```

What's the ruby way here ?

Comment: erm sorry can you rephrase the question it simply doesn't make sense

Comment: Given the string "content-management-systems" how do you get "Content Management Systems" string with Ruby ?

Then given "Content Management Systems" how do you get "content-management-systems" ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is tricky one:

```
puts "content-management-systems".split("-").map(&:capitalize).join(" ").
     tap{ |str| puts str}.
     split.map(&:downcase).join("-")

#=> Content Management Systems
#=> content-management-systems
```

The simplified variant:

```
"content-management-systems".split("-").map(&:capitalize).join(" ") 
#=> Content Management Systems

"Content Management Systems".split.map(&:downcase).join("-")
#=> content-management-systems
```

The clean variant (from Micheal):

```
"content-management-systems".split("-").map(&:capitalize).join(" ").
split(" ").map(&:downcase).join("-")
```

Comment: And the complete round-trip: `"content-management-systems".split("-").map(&:capitalize).join(" ").split(" ").map(&:downcase).join("-")`

Comment: Wow! That's great, you rocks!

Answer (score 2):

`gsub` regexp matches can be manipulated in block mode.

```
"content-management-systems".
  gsub(/(\w+)(-)?/) { ($2 ? $1 + " " : $1).capitalize! }.
  gsub(/(\w+)(\s)?/) { ($2 ? $1 + "-" : $1).downcase! }
```

and as these benchmark shows not much difference between regexp and
noregexp versions.

```
require 'benchmark'

STR = "content-management-systems".freeze

Benchmark.bmbm(10) do |x|
  x.report("noregexp") {
    STR.split("-").map(&:capitalize).join(" ").
    split(" ").map(&:downcase).join("-")
  }

  x.report("rgexp") {
    STR.
    gsub(/(\w+)(-)?/) { ($2 ? $1 + " " : $1).capitalize! }.
    gsub(/(\w+)(\s)?/) { ($2 ? $1 + "-" : $1).downcase! }
  }
end

__END__

Rehearsal ----------------------------------------------
noregexp     0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000032)
rgexp        0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000035)
------------------------------------- total: 0.000000sec

                 user     system      total        real
noregexp     0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000051)
rgexp        0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000058)
```

Answer (score 1):

I post this just to remember that ... 
regex just double computation time :

```
1.9.2p290 :014 > time = Benchmark.measure do
1.9.2p290 :015 >     puts "content-management-systems".split("-").map(&:capitalize).join(" ").
1.9.2p290 :016 >          tap{ |str| puts str}.
1.9.2p290 :017 >          split.map(&:downcase).join("-")
1.9.2p290 :018?>   end
Content Management Systems
content-management-systems
 =>   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000077)

1.9.2p290 :019 > time = Benchmark.measure do
1.9.2p290 :020 >     "content-management-systems".gsub(/(\w+)(-)?/) { ($2 ? $1 + " " : $1).capitalize! }
1.9.2p290 :021?>   "Content Management Systems".gsub(/(\w+)(\s)?/) { ($2 ? $1 + "-" : $1).downcase! }
1.9.2p290 :022?>   end
 =>   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000164)
```

and I'd like to thanks all contribution :-)

Comment: Thanks for the data! Regexp is never as fast as manual manipulation, but it is pretty fancy... and maybe faster in coding if you know regexp well

Comment: @Luca G. Soave, In this case you don't need to use 'tap{ |str| puts str}'

Comment: @megas correct, in that case is even a bit faster (0.000010 less)